# AWS CLI Athena,Python - pass query programmatically

Tags: sql, python-2.7, boto3, aws-cli, amazon-athena

I am trying to run a set of Athena SQL statements through the AWS CLI commands  and I need to know the following

The set of SQL queries are in a file and I need to sequentially iterate the --query-string in the following CLI command for each query through a python script

I can use FOR loop to get the sql commands from the file but I don't know how to parameterize it in AWS CLI command.

### AWS CLI Command

```
aws athena start-query-execution \
   --query-string **"select count(*) from tablename;"** \
   --query-execution-context Database=test45 \
   --result-configuration OutputLocation=s3://test/ \
   --output text
```

### Python Code

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('athena')
fd = open('Athenacli.sql', 'r')
sqlFile = fd.read()
fd.close()

sqlCommands = sqlFile.split(';')
for command in sqlCommands:
    print command
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=command,
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': 'Test45'
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': 's3://test/'
        }
    )

print response
```

### File content for Athenacli.sql

```
select count(*) CNT from Test45.table1;
```

### Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
     pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:/Python27/mypycode/CLIFrame.py", line 18, in <module>
    'OutputLocation': 's3://test/'
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 253, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 531, in _make_api_call
    api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 586, in _convert_to_request_dict
    api_params, operation_model)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\botocore\validate.py", line 291, in serialize_to_request
    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid length for parameter QueryString, value: 0, valid range: 1-inf

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is your whole problem, but you are splitting on ";" so you will get two queries, the first:

```
select count(*) CNT from Test45.table1
```

and the second:

```
""
```

This might explain the error message:

```
Invalid length for parameter QueryString, value: 0, valid range: 1-inf
```

Do you get any output before the error?

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='' read -r sql || [[ -n "$sql" ]]; do
    aws athena start-query-execution \
    --query-string "$sql" \
    --query-execution-context Database=test45 \
    --result-configuration OutputLocation=s3://test/ \
    --output text
done < "$1"
```

You can call your file `run_athena_query.sh`:

```
$ chmod +x run_athena_query.sh
$ ./run_athena_query.sh <file_with_query>
```

Comment: Thanks,is there any python equivalent code to achieve the same?

Comment: sure, support for Athena has been introduced to boto lib - see http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/athena.html

Comment: Thanks again.I tried with boto3 but it works fine when i provide a query in parameter --query-string but when i try to run for multiple query it fails.I have updated the code and error message in the question.